# Identifier not found error when compiling a c++ project with qt and opengl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I am trying to compile a C++ program which uses QT and opengl.

When I try to compile it, I am getting this error:

```
 Error  1   error C3861: 'gluErrorString': identifier not found
```

Looking for this identifier, showed me that it is defined in: line 64 on glu.h file which is part of VS 2012 installation.

Why am I getting this error?

I know that the source code was developed using VS 2010, but I think there should not be any difference, if I use VS 2012.

Should I make any changes to project setup?

Comment: @Jaochim - this is not the issue since this is a compiler error and not a linker errir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check that you have the line:

```
#include <glu.h>
```

somewhere.

Failing that open `glu.h` and ensure that there are no `#define`s that are preventing the line being included. You may have to add extra defines to your project.

It can sometime be useful to just run the preprocessor (not sure how to do this in VS) and ensure the symbol is ending up in your cpp file.

Comment: In VS, you can open a source file's properties (usually by right-clicking on it in the solution view), going to `C/C++ > Preprocessor > Generate preprocessed file`.

Comment: @Angew Where the generated file is saved?

Comment: @mans I believe it's normally next to the source file. Its extension is `.i`

Answer (score 0):

After adding the header glu.h also you may get a link error for unresolved symbol gluErrorString. You can solve this by adding the glu32.lib library in the input libraries of the project settings.